# Radio or podcasts for French language learners?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage, radio

I'm looking for some French radio (preferably available online) which is good for French language learners. Not necessarily for beginners or learners specifically (though don't mind to get recommendations on these options too), but let's say something like BBC Radio 4 where loads of audio plays are  aired. I've tried listening to BFM (Business) radio — but the pace of speech there is too quick for beginners and I'm looking for other options.

Comment: http://www.franceculture.fr/podcasts ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas en France l'équivalent de Radio 4 qui est un mélange de [France Culture](http://www.franceculture.fr/), [France Inter](http://www.franceinter.fr/) et [France Musique](http://www.francemusique.fr/). À essayer :  [Canal Académie](http://www.canalacademie.com/), radio de niveau universitaire avec certaines émissions en [écoute facile](http://www.canalacademie.com/idr161-En-francais-facile-portraits-.html) destinées « aux personnes dont le français n’est pas la langue maternelle ».

Comment: Voir aussi l'[espace apprendre](http://www.canalacademie.com/apprendre/) de Canal Académie fait pour ceux qui apprennent le français  langue étrangère et veulent « développer leurs connaissances de la langue et de la culture françaises ». On peut choir son thème, télécharger les podcasts, il y a des fiches de travail, des explications, des sujets de réflexion, le transcript des podcasts.

Answer (score 4):

Try [tunein.com](http://tunein.com/) and search for "French Talk". You will get a few hundreds of French-talking radio stations.

Something else that I found interesting while learning French was to follow dictation for children, like this one: [www.ladictee.fr](http://www.ladictee.fr/contenu/concours/dictee_concours_orthographe.htm)

For radio stations, I particulary like Radio France Internationale, especially the section ["apprendre, enseigner la langue française"](https://savoirs.rfi.fr/fr/apprendre-enseigner)

Answer (score 2):

Try [ARTE RADIO](http://www.arteradio.com/).

If you understand [Vengeance à l'albanaise](http://www.arteradio.com/son/616289/vengeance_a_l_albanaise/) (2mn), it's ok. Try other *reportages* on this site.

If not, listen the marvellous [La vache et le Peul](http://www.arteradio.com/son/616195/la_vache_et_le_peul/) (but... 7mn ! ). Then try [RFM](http://www.rfm.fr).

Answer (score 2):

You can try also RMC http://www.rmc.fr/emission-radio/podcasts/

Maybe you can listen more various topic instead of BFM Business :)

Answer (score 2):

Download the free "Radio Francaise" application for iPhone/iPad.  It has tons of stations including ones from different regions of France as well as from other francophone regions outside of France.  If you want something that is easier to follow then listen to news programs from "France Info" and "RFI Monde".  RMC can be more for advanced learners if you listen to their sports programs like Vincent Moscato.

You can also download the iPhone/iPad application for M6 and actually watch and listen to their news programs.  It is one of the few stations that you can access from outside of France.

Answer (score 1):

I love

newsinslowfrench.com

It is for true beginners.

Comment: This one looks good, but it's not free, it doesn't offer even some limited free access, you can only try a tiny sample before signing up for paid subscription  :( Though I like what I saw/heard - seems to be helpful as you can built up your vocabulary along with making a connection between spelling and pronounciation...

Answer (score 1):

You can look for French podcasts on iTUnes - there are **loads** of them. Some are for French learners.

Still on podcast, you can also have a look here:

http://baladoquebec.ca/

I enjoy listening podcasts from this site:

http://facteurgeek.com/

Believe me: they are flipping tough to understand. I can understand 10% at best **but** I usually listen to them when in the tube or something so if I can get 10%, well, that already helped me improve my listening a tiny bit.

Radio Canada is available online:

http://www.cbc.ca/radio/

In the upper-right corner there is a panel where you can choose one of the three channels to listen to.

BTW Radio Canada has an app for Android (and [I think] iPhone). The app is a bit funky but it gets the job done so you can listen to the radio when you are on the street, in a bus, waiting in line or something.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what has been said before, RTBF (Belgium) and RTS (Switzerland) are good to listen to as well.